# What is the easiest way to solve matrix inverse using python

Tags: python

I Wanted to solve matrix inverse without calling numpy into python. I want to know if it possible or not.

Comment: It is, just code it on your own using nested lists.

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Either use an existing library, like numpy, or write your own..

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Of course you can try to implement the inverse of a matrix yourself, although the implementation in `numpy` will be very probably faster.... Anyway, your question, as you have formulated it, is very broad. An answer could be "yes, it is possible", or could be many other things. Please try to narrow it. Thanks.

Comment: Well of course it's possible - as you mentioned, [numpy does it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html), doesn't it? I'd say the best way for you to learn is to look at the [source code of numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/66156a049aa833a06e6747dbe88676a61e034e8d/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src).

Answer (score 1):

your question title:

> What is the easiest way to solve matrix inverse using python

```
import numpy
numpy.linalg.inv(your_matrix)
```

or the same with `scipy` instead of `numpy` -- that's definitely the *easiest*, for you as a programmer.

What is your reason not to use `numpy`?

You can of course [look for an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution) and implement it manually. But the built-in function are based on the Fortran LAPACK algorithms, which are tested and optimized for the last 50 years... they will be hard to surpass...

Comment: If you already have a `numpy` `matrix`, you can even just use the property `I` to invert the matrix, like `your_matrix.I`.